# Instaling SQL Server from command line

Tags: sql-server

Could someone kindly advise me what are the command line parameters for:

1. Setting Status, Setting are done automatically as ‘Permission to Connect to DB Engine is Grant and ‘Login’ is Enabled (by default it is Disabled)
2. Setting ‘Local and Remote Connections’ with Using TCP / IP only’Grant

Thanks

Comment: which Version e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.90).aspx  or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405(v=sql.100).aspx